# 500 Error on domain after upgrading to PHP5.6/Apache 2.4, ip works fine!? Nothing in Logs

Tags: apache

I have a 500 error on one of my sites after upgrading to PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4. All other sites work fine on the server apart from this specific one.

If I create a new /public_html directory and stick in a brand new index.html I still get the same problem so its nothing to do with bad PHP files or .htaccess or file permissions.

If I use the dedicated IP instead its fine!

I cant work out what else could be causing this problem, there is nothing in the logs either?

any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an apache configuration issue. Have you looked at the apache error log? Since HTML doesnt work either, the PHP seems irrelevant.

Comment: yep absolutely nothing in the error logs!

Comment: You might want to try serverfault in that case.

Comment: thanks, asked there